# Excel Filter for the whole row content or display search result as rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, search

I'm looking for an option to search/filter in an excel workbook for strings to get the results as whole rows.

Is there a way to search trough the whole workbook for a string but present the result in a nice way:
* display the whole row with the found cell content highlighted
* not in this freaking unhandy little dialog box each cell on its on

Or another option if this is not working - a better filter to filter on whole rows not only on the content of one cell (column wise). Basically I know that with `Data -> Filter` it is possible to filter for rows containing the search string in the filer column. 
But what I need would be a filter based on all columns at once. Is there something like that?

One way or the other both would help a lot.

Comment: Is this something that you want to happen as soon as the string is entered? (conditional formatting). Or when you specifically make a search for that string? (probably VBA)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do what you want from all sheets nor even 1 sheet. This is what databases do so well with relational filters and custom reports.

What I would do is see if there is a convenient way to string all the columns together inserted after the last column . A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&... then use the AutoFilter for *contains* xxx in that column and repeat for each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a combination of [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) and [filtering by colour](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/18/sort-by-color-excel/#filter-cells-color).

Select a cell `A2` (assuming that's where your data rows start), and apply a conditional format to change the cell's background fill based on this formula:

```
=NOT(ISNA(HLOOKUP(search_term,2:2, 1, FALSE)))
```

Apply a second conditional format to change the cell's text colour based on this formula:

```
=(A2=search_term)
```

You will either need to replace `search_term` in the formulae above with the string you want to search for, or [define the name](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) `search_term` to have the value you want to search for (which means you don't have to re-do all the formatting to change the search term later).

Use the format painter to copy the conditional formatting from cell `A2` to all your rows of data.

The first conditional format should highlight each row that contains your search string with a background colour.  You can then turn on filtering, and filter by colour to select just the matching rows.  The second format changes the text colour for the individual matching cells.  You could use a different background colour instead, but that would make the filtering harder.